# Render a js file on my homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use a js file in my homepage if the user is not completely registered to display a modal.

To do that I wrote :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :info_table, only: [:home]

  def home  
  end

  private 

  def info_table
    respond_to do |format|
      if current_user.name.nil?
        format.html { render "home" }
        format.js { render "pages/js/confirmation" }
      else
        format.html { render "home" }
        format.js { render "pages/js/confirmation" }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

`
And into my confirmation.js.erb :

```
alert("this is an alert !")
```

But nothing appeared !
Do you have an idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering html & js formats in both conditions

```
  if current_user.name.nil?
    format.html { render "home" }
    format.js { render "pages/js/confirmation" }
  else
    format.html { render "home" }
    format.js { render "pages/js/confirmation" }
  end
```

but only one format will render in actual which will depend on the request to that action, if you want to render js format you might want to do something like this

```
link_to 'Home' home_path, remote: true
```

or maybe

```
  if current_user.name.nil?
    format.js { render "pages/js/confirmation" }
  else
    format.html { render "home" }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some JS code to call your home method and have it being flagged as **JS**.

Otherwise it will only render the **html** block

The JS link suggested by @Sikandar Tariq is one good way. (the `, remote: true` make it an ajax call)